# setOnItemSelectedListener android

Tags: android, widget

Okay i have one spiner, this is my spinner

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("SPBU");
list.add("HOTEL");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
      dataAdapter
      .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spiner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

I want create OnItemSelectedListener method, so i can detect if selection changed.
The Problem is i dont know how to implement that, i do not understand what parameters to use in the method ( arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3 ). this what i try so far

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // my code here

            }
```

Comment: use this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know how a method works, checking the documentation is always a good idea.
Anyway, this will help you get started ;)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        list.add("SPBU");
        list.add("HOTEL");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on: " + list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        //do something
    }

}
```

EDIT:
you can also create an anonymous class to handle the event:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a listener for the spinner, which will call the "onItemSelected" method when the item is selected. Here's some sample code:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         //stuff here to handle item selection      
     }

     @Override
     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

     }
});
```